# How to change language of KDE software installed in Ubuntu

Tags: kde, language-support, internationalization

I would like to know how to change the language of the KDE software (Gwen and Okular) that I installed in my Ubuntu. My Ubuntu is in French, but the KDE software is in English. When I *"Switch the language"* in *"Help"*, it does not offer me that American English.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with Unity Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Install KDE System Settings there you can change the language. Make sure, you have the KDE language packages installed. If not, you have to install them too.

```
 sudo apt-get install systemsettings language-pack-kde-fr language-pack-kde-fr-base
```

[image: kde systemsettings screenshot]

Under **[Locale](http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Locale)** you can change the **Languages** settings.

[image: locale screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the wanted language packs
2. Start the KDE application with the `KDE_LANG`

   [Some important environment variables used by KDE:](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_desktop_guides/kde_desktop_user_guide/environment-variables.html)

   > `$ KDE_LANG`
   >
   > Overrides the KDE language configuration, e.g. `KDE_LANG=fr kprogram &` 
   >   starts a program with French translation if the necessary files are
   >   installed.

Comment: Seems not to work for me on 12.04.1 with `language-pack-kde-nl` installed and attempting to run `KDE_LANG=nl kate`, `KDE_LANG=nl_NL kate` or `KDE_LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 kate`.

Comment: @Buzz-dEE `LANG=en_US synaptic` works for me in a terminal. `LANG=en_US synaptic-pkexec` does not work for me in the launcher. My default language is English but my Synaptic Package Manager displays in Thai when launched.