# Why do some Applications use local language?

Tags: kde

I've set all entries in /etc/default/locale to "en_US.UTF-8" BUT some applications, eg. VLC Media Player, Synaptic Manager, still using local language! How to set default application language?

Comment: @Coditoergosum, how to do that? give me an example.

Comment: You can see this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/231062/how-to-change-language-of-kde-software-installed-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Coditoergosum, I've to set it manually for each app that using local language?

Comment: & here https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-language-settings-in-kde/

Comment: @Coditoergosum, before installing IBus and Local Phonetic Keyboard layout everything was ok, Now I've to write `Exec=LANG=en ...` manually in `/usr/share/applications/` for apps that use local language!